# MySQL Index performance for decimal column type

Tags: mysql

I searched everywhere but i couldn't find a proper answer about index on decimal columns types.

I have a table (innodb) with reviews, column score is decimal(3,1) mean there will be a number between 0.0 and 10.0
I have index on score column where i can order by desc my reviews.

What are the advices you can give me to make a good index on a decimal column? Is there any changes i need to make or this will be the right way to do the index?

Any infos are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your looking too soon, Make the index on it, if there are performance issues, solve them then. without knowing the query, simply adding an index to the column and letting MySQL sort it is by far the best way.

An alternative is storing between 0 and 100, which would be a TINYINT(In reality 0-255), Though you lose the meaning of the type and have to remember to divide by 10 each use.

Its MUCH better to just stay as you are and fix the problems as you come to them.